# Excel: Get unique Data from specific columns to another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my Excel `=Unique` function doesn't work, I want to get data from column “F” and get unique date values to column “P”.

[image]
Then use data in column “P” in another sheet where I will use this data as a list from the Data Validation feature on Excel.

I tried `IFERROR` functions shown on sites as well as `Filter Function` it works fine but when I want to use it as a `List` in another sheet then it shows some error.

Comment: Use the unique function in column p '=UNIQUE(F4:F24)' and make sure column P is not in an Excel Table.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

In the P-Column write `=UNIQUE(F1:F24)` (or whatever your data range is).

Then in the cells you want to add data validation, select "List" in the Data Validation Menu. For the *Source* Textbox, simply select the collection of cells in the P-Column populated by the "UNIQUE" function.

Let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be not creating a separate unique list in the first place. When you select a collection of cells under "List" in the Data Validation Menu, Excel **automatically** creates a unique list out of them. So here's what you could do-

Step 1: Select the cells you want Data Validation in.

Step 2: Select "List" in the Data Validation Menu.

Step 3: Select F1:F24 (or whatever your complete data range is)

Step 4: Press Ok

The cells now have a Data Validation list that contain unique values from the F-Column.